# Overwriting database with backup from older Drupal version?

Tags: database, updating, migrations, installation

I have a database from a live site I need to bring over to a development site.

live site = d7.7, outdated modules, but is obviously up to date with all the recent ubercart orders

dev site = d7.15, all modules updated, but is missing the latest ubercart orders

I had been migrating the live DB over to the dev site periodically, but now that the dev site is running newer modules and core, I'm wondering if its still safe to move migrate the database from the live 7.7 site.

can I migrate the database and simply run update.php afterward to catch up?

ubercart orders are really the only thing im concerned about. also, ubercart is one of the modules that has been updated on the dev site.

Complete list of modules that have been updated on the DEV site. Some of these required the running of update.php

Drush
CTools
Ubercart
Views
Entity
Token
Securepages
Rules
Admin Menu
Node Export
UUID
Pathauto
Gallery formatter
Twitter Pull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - in most cases, this should be a fairly straightforward operation. You should be able to migrate your updated modules from dev over to the live site and just run update to get everything running again. If there are going to be issues with this (for ex. a module that requires a little more configuration to get working), you can isolate these issues before-hand on your dev server (and it sounds like you've already done this successfully).

Most of the top contrib modules (ex. the ones you cite above) will be very careful at upgrading their structure without impacting any new data (or orders).

Comment: Well, what I'm doing is copying a database from a site with older modules, over to another site with newer modules.

live site = older modules, dev site = newer modules. Eventually the dev site will become the "live" site, and the currently-live site will be shut down entirely (I'm migrating from Godaddy to Linode.)

Comment: got it - you're still ok just running update.php. if you bring the live db down to dev, it will recognize that the modules are in a newer state than what is recorded in the systems table and suggest you run update.php -- just as if you had updated the modules code directly on your live site. All straightforward in Drupal, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Just make sure that you completely remove all database tables from the database before you load the backup because it will only overwrite tables that actually exist in the backup. Sometimes, modules add new tables in an update function and then the upgrade would fail if that table already exists.

Comment: Interesting.. I normally just do existingdb < newdbdump.sql, but I'm unclear whether this wipes out the existing db (as you suggest I should) or if it only overwrites matching tables? it sounds like I should just drop the existingdb entirely, re-make it with the same name (empty), and then import the data from the dump...